# How do I read a custom scss variable from javascript/typescript?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, sass

Say I need to share a variable (not a standard CSS value) between my SCSS and my Code (Typescript/JS)?

I need the variable in CSS for design, while in code for other aspects.

I thought about defining the variable in SCSS, and accessing it from Typescript (Angular2/Ionic2), but I can't understand how to do so. There are few examples in out there, but most are jQuery or just unfit for Ionic2/Angular2. I tried to define a class and add it to my ion-content, but I still cannot read my custom CSS properties/attributes(?) from it...

HTML:

```
...
<ion-content class="zozo">
...
```

TS:

```
@ViewChild( Content ) content: Content;

...

static getSassProperty( propName: string )
{
    let ne: HTMLElement = MyApp.me.content.getElementRef().nativeElement;
    let value = ne.style[ "--" + propName ];
    return value;
}
```

SCSS:

```
.zozo
{
    --cropper-width: $cropper-width;
    --cropper-height: $cropper-height;
}
```